# How do I get Powershell to read the contents of a file?

Tags: powershell, file-read

I'm adapting this script that counts the instances of a individual words in a file.

```
$txtPath = "c:\users\xxxxxx\desktop\tx"
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $txtPath -filter "*.txt*"
#
function wordCount ($docs) {
    Write-Host "Processing Word Count: " $docs
$s = "I saw the cat. The cat was black."
",",".","!","?",">","<","&","*","=","`n","_" |% {$s = $s.replace($_,' ')}     # Remove Chars
$w = $s.Split() |? {$_.Length -gt 0 }                                     # Array of words, spaces removed
$w | select -Unique                                                       # Unique words
$w | group                                                                # Tally
$W | group | sort name | ft name,count -AutoSize              # Sort and format
#>
}
#
ForEach ($doc in $srcfiles) { 
    Write-Host "Calling: " $doc.FullName         
    wordCount -docs  $doc.FullName    
}
```

Currently the input variable `$s`, representing the string to be counted, is hardcoded. I would like to take each document in my `$srcFiles` path and run the count on each. However, `$s = $docs` counts the words in the title, not the document content. How do I do that?

Also, `$W | group | sort name | ft name,count -AutoSize` returns the following error:

```
out-lineoutput : The object of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" is not valid or not
 in the correct sequence. This is likely caused by a user-specified "format-table" command which is conflicting with th
e default formatting.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [out-lineoutput], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConsoleLineOutputOutOfSequencePacket,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
```

Where should I look for formatting problems? I wasn't able to spot any kinds of default formatting information on TechNet; and the [site](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/02/27/hey-powershell-guy-how-can-i-tally-up-all-the-words-found-in-a-text-file.aspx) that this code originally came from makes no mention of how they made it work, nor which default formats they were overriding. I suspect I may need to pipe it differently, but I need to better understand the exact error so I know where to start hunting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Get-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx) to read the contents of the file. You will need to combine the lines returned by Get-Content to correctly count the characters. See this [post](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/789.aspx).

Comment: Or in V3, use `Get-Content -Raw` to get back a single string with all the file's contents. On v1/v2 I would use `[IO.File]::ReadAllText()`.  :-)

Comment: Didn't know about that parameter. Awesome!